# How to add a code template for all projects in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to add a code template for Java files for the Eclipse plugin my team develop. For now it is just the copyright notice.

I can easily do it in my workspace and in a project. Is there a way to apply the change to all projects of my plugin, besides copy/pasting the change for each project?

The desired solution should be shared among all team members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the New Java files template to have your contents per-project. That will create a file in the project root's `.settings` folder you could likely copy through all of your plug-in projects.

[image: Java Code Templates Property Page]

For just the copyright notice, you can probably make use of the Copyright Tool in the platform releng tools. It will iterate through your sources looking for files that need a copyright comment added at the beginning, and even update an existing comment when certain conditions are met:

1. The project is stored in git
2. The file type is supported by the tool
3. The first comment is a block comment, not a line comment.
4. The first comment contains "copyright" followed by a year

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool

Comment: Great suggestion nitind! I like it, however it has the disadvantage that it is not automated. The developer must still remember to click "Fix Copyright". At the moment I guess I want to go with a combination of your solution + a code template for every project.

Comment: I edited my question with the requirement to have a solution working for the whole team.

Answer (score 0):

Not with the template mechanism. You should be able to do this with a smart Find and Replace though. Use the Search > File search to open the search dialog, put the existing copyright text (depending on how you want to run the replace) in the *Containing text* field, set the *File name pattern* to `*.java` and *Scope* to Workspace. Then use the Replace button.

If you need new lines or tabs inserted, you should mark your source string as a regular expression, so that in the replace field, `\n` will result in the addition of a new line, else you will just get `\n` in your text.

Comment: Thank you Brian. This does not help me, unfortunately. I need something that is accessible from the whole team, and automatized.